# ehcache failed in production environment

Tags: spring, hibernate, networking, spring-mvc, centos

I am developing an `SpringMVC` application in following version :

```
Spring 3.2.0, Hibernate 3.6.9
```

Echache

It works fine on windows environment with `Tomcat 6.18` (in development), but when we deployed into production environment (`Cent OS`), it gives the following error and deployment gets failed.

I am getting exactly what is root cause.

```
2013-02-18 12:42:16,941 -  - Unable to set localhost. This prevents creation of a GUID. Cause was: static-182-18-145-83.ctrls.in: static-182-18-145-83.ctrls.in
java.net.UnknownHostException: static-182-18-145-83.ctrls.in: static-182-18-145-83.ctrls.in
    at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1360)
    at net.sf.ehcache.Cache.<clinit>(Cache.java:200)
    at net.sf.ehcache.config.ConfigurationHelper.createCache(ConfigurationHelper.java:302)
    at net.sf.ehcache.config.ConfigurationHelper.createDefaultCache(ConfigurationHelper.java:218)
    at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.configure(CacheManager.java:599)
    at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.init(CacheManager.java:358)
    at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.<init>(CacheManager.java:272)
    at org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider.start(EhCacheProvider.java:134)
    at org.hibernate.cache.impl.bridge.RegionFactoryCacheProviderBridge.start(RegionFactoryCacheProviderBridge.java:72)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:238)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1872)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:906)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:74)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:286)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:310)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1545)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
```

Comment: It seems to me the code is unable to resolve localhost on your production machine. Consult your network administrator, on many production environment localhost resolution is disabled for security reason. Maybe also consult ehcache documentation how to bind into another address

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is related with `hostname`

```
127.0.0.1   work        localhost
```

to your /etc/hosts file

you can do this by executing

sudo bash

```
echo "127.0.0.1 localhost mynap3" >> /etc/hosts
```